# put the current thread to sleep and let others wake it

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have the follow method `foo` which takes an Observer and puts the current thread to sleep until the Observer wakes it up.

For some reason, I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` exception in `foo`

```
public void foo(Observer o)
{
    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    o.setThread(currentThread);
    // sleep until the observer wakes it
    currentThread.wait(2000);   // <<<<< Exception happens here
}
```

The `Observer` object would call `currentThread.notifyAll()` sometime later when its `Observable` calls `update` on it.

```
public class Observer
{
    private volatile Thread currentThread;
    // ... other code  ....

   public void setThread(Thread t)
   {
       currentThread = t;
   }

   public void update(Observable o)
   {
        currentThread.notify();
   }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IllegalMonitorStateException on wait() call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553886/java-lang-illegalmonitorstateexception-m-null-failed-to-get-monitor-for seems pertinent.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's of any help, but have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886722/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java

Comment: That's is NOT the same as this question. I cannot put `synchronized` in `foo` because that would cause the thread to sleep forever. (See my comment below in one of the question!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you call [`wait(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) or [`notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) method of object , that thread must own the monitor of that object. So you should declare your block of code calling `wait()` on the object to be `synchronized` . So your method

```
public void foo(Observer o)
```

should be defined in following way:

```
public void foo(Observer o)
{
    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    o.setThread(currentThread);
    // sleep until the observer wakes it
    synchronized(currentThread)
    {
      currentThread.wait(2000);   
    }
 }
```

**UPDATE:** 
Going by your requirement I suggest you that you should call `wait` on `Observer` object . So your code for `foo` should be something like this:

```
public void foo(Observer o)
{
    synchronized(o)
    {
      o.wait();//Don't pass time as parameter. Let only the Observer object to wake it up.
    }
 }
```

And your `Observer`  class should be defined in this way:

```
public class Observer
{
    // ... other code  ....

   /*public void setThread(Thread t)
   {
       currentThread = t;
   }*/
   public synchronized void update(Observable o)
   {
        notify();//Will wake up the Thread waiting on the current Object of Observer
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what object should I call? I don't really have an object for sharing. All the I want to do is for the function `foo` to put the current executing thread to  sleep and let the `Observer` wake it.

Comment: Why would `foo` be declared as synchronized? I can guarantee that it is not going to be called concurrently.

Comment: Yes you are right..`foo` should not be synchronized, instead  `synchronized` should be called on object `currentThread` for the block of code that is calling `wait` method on `currentThread`

Comment: If i add synchronized(currentThread) in foo, the Observer.update would not be able to get access to currentThread because the Observer.update will be called in a different thread from the one foo is executing, which means foo will be sleeping forever, because it is holding currentThread while it sleeps, so update would not be able to wake it)

Comment: `foo` will not be sleeping forever as you have mentioned the time(`2 s`) for which the Thread will wait . See my updated Post..

Answer (score 2):

> That's is NOT the same as this question. I cannot put synchronized in foo because that would cause the thread to sleep forever.

I don't think you are understanding how `wait()` and `notify()` work.  You do *not* wait and notify on the threads, you do it on the same *object*.  When your code does:

```
currentThread.wait(2000);
```

it is actually causing the current thread to wait on it's own `Thread` object.  The way to `notify()` that thread would then be something like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
...
thread.notify();
```

This is a *very* strange pattern and is most likely *not* what you want to do.  It shouldn't matter which thread is running the `foo()` method.  If you were using a thread-pool you wouldn't even know which thread was running it.

If you want your `Observer` thread to notify the thread waiting in `foo()` then they both need to be working with the same lock object.  Something like:

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    public synchronized void foo() {
        // this is waiting on the current instance of MyClass
        wait(2000);
    }
}

public class Observer {
     ...
     // to wake up the other thread, we lock the same myClass instance
     synchronized (myClass) {
         // and notify that object
         myClass.notify();
     }
}
```

Or you could create a lock object that they both should share.

```
final Object lockObject = new Object();
MyClass c1 = new MyClass(lockObject);
Observer obs = new Observer(lockObject();
...
class MyClass {
    private final Object lockObject;
    public MyClass(Object lockObject) {
        this.lockObject = lockObject;
    }
    ...
    public void foo() {
        // this is waiting on the current instance of MyClass
        synchronized (lockObject) {
            lockObject.wait(2000);
        }
    }
}
...
public class Observer {
    private final Object lockObject;
    public Observer(Object lockObject) {
        this.lockObject = lockObject;
    }
    public void update(Observable o) {
        synchronized (lockObject) {
            lockObject.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

FYI: Lock objects should almost always be `final` so they can't change their reference.   You never want to lock on something that changes like an `Integer` or a `Boolean`.

Comment: Ok, firstly I agreed with you that I misunderstood the meaning of `wait` and `sleep`. But I don't think your suggestions (especially the second one) would solve my problem (, though I might be wrong (again!)). So let me clarify what I am try to do. (in the second comment, since it'd be too long here)

Comment: I don't have an object that I need to be 'locked on'. All I want to do is for `foo` to put whatever thread currently calling `foo` to sleep, until the given `observer` (the argument to `foo`) wakes it up. The `observer` would be observing some background task elsewhere. It needs to wake the thread calling `foo` up after the background task that it is observing has finished. (`foo` would actually be `static`, by the way.)

Comment: Is there one instance of the object that has `foo()` in it or multiple instances?  You can't  call `notify()` on that object?

Comment: As I said, `foo` is `static`, so it is some sort of library function that anyone can call to wait until the `observer` says some background task has finished.

Comment: The only way to do that @OneTwoThree is to have the library function and the `Observer` share the same object.  It could be a `BlockingQueue` or something instead of a lock-object but there is no other way to accomplish what you want unless you want to do a socket connection to an agreed upon port or something.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer not yo use `wait` or `notify` as it is low level and gets dirty quickly if not well implemented. It can be solved through binary semaphore.

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
public void foo(Semaphore f){
    f.acquire();
}
```

Other thread, can later call `f.release` which will unblock the other thread

Answer (score 0):

To use [java.lang.Object.wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) you have to own the monitor, it's usually done by a [synchronized block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19):

```
public void foo( Observer o ) throws InterruptedException
{
   Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
   o.setThread( currentThread );
   synchronized( currentThread ) {
      currentThread.wait( 2000 );
   }
}
```

Add the same mechanism around notify()

```
public void update( Observable o ) throws InterruptedException {
   synchronized( currentThread ) {
      currentThread.notify();
   }
```

}

Comment: If i add `synchronized(currentThread)`  in foo, the `Observer.update` would not be able to get access to `currentThread` because the `Observer.update` will be called in a different thread from the one `foo` is executing, which means `foo` will be sleeping forever, because it is holding `currentThread` while it sleeps, so `update` would not be able to wake it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a synchronized. When you will call currentThread.wait(), the thread will sleep and will free the monitor (currentThread). This thread will after be waiting to be waked up by another thread with a notify() on the same monitor.